# convert string to int32 with LSB c#

Tags: c#, string

I have binary string and Int32 array.

How to convert binary string (each 11 bit of string) to Int32 value(11 LSB) on int array?

I tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <(string.Length); i++) { 
    if (count1 >= string.Length - 21) 
        break; 
    else 
        string = string.Insert(count1, "000000000000000000000"); 
        count1 += 31; 
} 
int numOfBytes = string.Length / 32; 
int[] ints = new int[numOfBytes]; 
for (int i = 0; i < numOfBytes; ++i) { 
    ints[i] = Convert.ToInt32(string.Substring(32 * i, 32), 2); 
}
```

but it returns false values

Comment: Well, have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Have you try `Convert.ToInt32`? Read more about the function at [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: yes, I tried this `for (int i = 0; i <(string.Length); i++)
            {
               if (count1 >= cstring.Length - 21) break;
     else
                  string = cipher_reverse_diff_string.Insert(count1, "000000000000000000000");
        count1 += 31;
         
            }

            int numOfBytes = string.Length / 32;
            int[] ints = new int[numOfBytes];
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfBytes; ++i)
            {
                ints[i] = Convert.ToInt32(string.Substring(32 * i, 32), 2);
            }   ` but it returns false values @Camilo terevinto

Comment: @MSc You should [edit] the question so that the code is readable.

Comment: @lamandy yes I tried it,but want each 11 bit of string became a value on the int array,so , it doesn't useful for me

Comment: Take every 11 characters from the string as substring and pass to the function then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Int32[] BinaryStringToInt32Array(const string binaryString, const int bitCount)
{
    Int32[] results = new Int32[binaryString.Length/bitCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
    {
        string str = binaryString.Substring(i * bitCount, bitCount);
        results[i] = Convert.ToInt32(str, 2);
    }

    return results;

}
```

Take note this function will ignore all leftover bits if binaryString's length is not multiple of bitCount. In your case, bitCount is 11.

Comment: It's Worked ! Great ! Thank you :) I will make it as accepted answer, can you please explain the note for me ?

Comment: Essentially, take every 11 characters from the string and pass to `Convert.ToInt32` to get the Int32 value. The second parameter is to indicate it is base 2.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation , but i meant this note "Take note this function will ignore all leftover bits if binaryString's length is not multiple of bitCount".

Comment: Ahh, let's say your binaryString has 12 characters. The first 11 characters are going to be processed and the leftover last character is going to be ignored.